# get code between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery, is there a  way to capture all the code between two divs?

For example; using the code below, if Show info is clicked than the code between the ws-css-table divs should be retrieved, i.e.

```
<div class="ws-css-table-tr"><div class="ws-css-table-td">A</div>... <div class="ws-css-table-td">D</div></div>
```

should be put into a text variable.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blueberrymuffin/vy5mok8k/1/) for the current code.

Thanks for any help.

```
<div class="ws-css-table">
    <div class="ws-css-table-tr">
        <div class="ws-css-table-td">A</div>
        <div class="ws-css-table-td">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ws-css-table-tr">
        <div class="ws-css-table-td">C</div>
        <div class="ws-css-table-td">D</div>
    </div>
</div>

    </br>
<div class='show_div_info'>Show info</div>
```

jquery

```
 $(".show_div_info").click(function(){
  alert ("info?")
});
```

Comment: Depends how many `div`s there are of class `ws-css-table` in the document. Might be easier to give it an id and target it: `$('#el').html()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the classic javascript and a single liner technique using `innerHTML`:

```
 $(".show_div_info").click(function(){
  alert($('.ws-css-table')[0].innerHTML);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vy5mok8k/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(".show_div_info").click(function(){
    var children = $(".ws-css-table").html();
  $(".children").html(children);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vy5mok8k/2/

Comment: This code will do just what I wanted. And you answered so fast! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to capture the elements inside the table and do something with it later?

```
$(".show_div_info").click(function(){
    var table = $(".ws-css-table");
    // Do something
});
```

Do you mean to capture the literal code inside the table? Say hello to the [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function:

```
$(".show_div_info").click(function(){
    var table = $(".ws-css-table").html();
    // Do something
});
```

Do you mean to capture the actual text inside the table? Say hello to the [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function:

```
$(".show_div_info").click(function(){
    var table = $(".ws-css-table").text();
    // Do something
});
```

The more practical one would be the first one, since you will be able to use it to manipulate the elements inside as you need.

Second one just grabs the actual code, perhaps you need it to show off your awesome skills.

The last one will print the text, neat if you use it to parse or log what you have thus far done.

How did that help?

Comment: Your examples assume there's only one class of that type in the document. I don't think you can make that assumption.

Comment: @Andy The implementation described by the OP is the base for the solution, they can easily change the selector to be more strict/unique by using an `id` instead.

Comment: The second example was what I was looking for. I did simplify my code, there would be more than 1 class inside the divs, but I think it should still work. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user1763812 don't forget that as Andy suggested, you can make your life easier by using a better selector. Using an `id` is fast, but you can also select all tables and match whichever one you need by index... it all depends on what your implementation actually does.

Comment: @user1763812 also make sure to select the answer which was most helpful, for all users who may benefit from your question, I'm glad we could help out.